# Why does a map insert change the object member values?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class Car {
public:
    Car( float costs, float speed) : costs(costs), speed(speed){}; 

    float getSpeed() const {
        return speed;
    }

    float getCosts() const {
        return costs;
    }

private:
    float costs;
    float speed;
};


class CarManager {
public: 

    CarManager(){};

    void assignCars( std::vector<Car> &cars){
        float costs = 1000.0;

        float inc_costs = 700.0;
        float inc_speed = 50.0; 

        for (size_t i = 0; i <= 10; ++i) {
            float speed = 10.0;
            std::vector<Car*> car_vec;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {

                if (j >= i) {
                    cars.push_back(Car(costs, speed));
                    car_vec.push_back(&cars.back());
                }
                speed += inc_speed;
            }

            car_storage.insert( {costs , car_vec }  );
            costs += inc_costs;
        }
    }

    void print(){
        for (const auto & p : car_storage) {
            std::cout << "map[" << p.first << "] = ";
            for (const auto & s : p.second) {   
                    std::cout << "[" << s->getSpeed() <<", " << s->getCosts() << "] , ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    std::map<float, std::vector<Car*> > car_storage;
};

int main()
{

    std::vector<Car> cars;
    CarManager car_manager;
    car_manager.assignCars(cars);
    car_manager.print();

}
```

The [printout](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12ebcf299fbc44bf) somehow differs from what I expect. I push a Car with costs and speed into a vector [`cars.push_back(Car(costs, speed))`] and later push a pointer to this `Car` in a local vector of `Car*`: `car_vec.push_back(&cars.back())`. Next, I insert the key (`costs`) and the value (`car_vec`) into the map. When I print the map out, the values aren't correct anymore.

In the first case for example:
first loop `i = 0`, inner loop `j`, thus (j >= i) and I push_back a `Car( 1000.0,  10.0)`. What's contained in the map, later on, is simply a `Car(0,0)`. For the other cars, this applies as well, but they have some strange values.

```
map[1000] = [0, 0] , [0, 7.41086e-38] , [0, 7.41063e-38] , [0, 7.41064e-38] , [210, 1700] , 

map[1700] = [0, 7.41092e-38] , [0, 7.41094e-38] , [0, 7.41094e-38] , [210, 1700] , 

map[2400] = [110, 2400] , [160, 2400] , [210, 2400] , 

map[3100] = [160, 3100] , [210, 3100] , 

map[3800] = [210, 3800] ,
```

I have no clue what is going on. Debugging showed me, that the values have been ok until they get inserted into the map at `car_storage.insert( {costs , car_vec }  )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you write this:

```
cars.push_back(Car(costs, speed))
car_vec.push_back(&cars.back())
```

? You create a `Car` and push it's *copy* to the `cars` vector. On the next line you push a *pointer to the copy in this vector*. Never do it! On any further operation with first vector's size change like `push_back`, `clear` and so on it may reallocate all it's content. I.e. it takes new memory fragment, copies values there, deletes the old one. Old pointers to it's content become invalid.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that only a copy gets pushed. I thought since C++11 a `std::move()` would be done. Would a fix then be to use emplace_back? or how would I solve this?

Comment: @SeanM. `emplace_back` allows you to construct an object without copy. But address of `cars.back()` stills be possible to change any time. Maybe a good way is to keep a vector of pointers. It is meant to be a good form to keep a pointers vector for possibly "heavy" user classes. If you don't want to manage memory manually, consider _vector<[unique_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/?kw=unique_ptr)>_ or _vector<[shared_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/?kw=shared_ptr)>_.

Comment: @SeanM. You are right, in this code temporary object will be _moved_ since C++11. But I don't think that it has any difference for this class. Anyway, the problem is not a copy. It is a pointer to address-changeable or local variable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'll have a closer look at smart pointers then.

Comment: Shouldn't this (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67e4e367d33b272a) be the expected behaviour I intended with my earlier code?

Comment: @SeanM., no. Your `CarManager` contains copies of `Car`s. If you want it to manipulate with the same cars (what do you really want?), input vector should be a vector of pointers too. One more thing is that you move a `unique_ptr` and then dereference it. It will dereference `NULL`.